# Easy way to convert data table to hash table or sqldatareader to hashtable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, jquery

Is there an easy way to convert a `DataTable` to a `HashTable` or a `SQLDataReader` to a `HashTable`?  I have to parse it through javascriptserializer. The code I am using has some problems:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            dt.Load(dr);
        }
    }

    Hashtable sendData = new Hashtable();

    foreach (DataRow drIn in dt.Rows)
    {

        sendData.Add(drIn["orderNumber"].ToString(), drIn["customerName"].ToString());

    }

    sendData.Add("orderNum", order);
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string output = jss.Serialize(sendData);
    return output;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Message + "-" + ex.StackTrace;
}
```

It is giving a correct result when queried from one table in the database but from another table it's having a problem.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please decribe the problem, with the exact error message.

Comment: Can you please post the problem i.e. which scenario its breaking

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function to convert DataTable to HashTable,

```
public static Hashtable convertDataTableToHashTable(DataTable dtIn,string keyField,string valueField)   
{    
   Hashtable htOut = new Hashtable();    
   foreach(DataRow drIn in dtIn.Rows)    
   {    
      htOut.Add(drIn[keyField].ToString(),drIn[valueField].ToString());    
   }   
   return htOut;    
}
```

Then in your code just use,

```
Hashtable sendData = new Hashtable();
//You need to pass datatable, key field and value field
sendData = convertDataTableToHashTable(dt, "orderNumber", "customerName");
```

Comment: Reference: https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2006/05/03/converting-a-datatable-to-a-hashtable/

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to create your own extension methods for this, as this is kind of specific desired behavior.

```
public static class DataTableExtensions 
{
    public static Hashtable ToHashtable(this DataTable dt, string key, string value)
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ht.Add(row[key].ToString(), row[value].ToString());
        }
        return ht;
    }

    public static Hashtable ToHashtable(this DataTable dt, int keyIndex, int valueIndex)
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ht.Add(row[keyIndex].ToString(), row[valueIndex].ToString());
        }
        return ht;
    }
}
```

and here are some example use cases:

```
public class SomeClass{
    static void NormalWay(){
        DataTable dt = Library.RandomDataTable(); // Go get SQL Data
        Hashtable ht = dt.ToHashtable("some key column", "some value column");
        // Build a hashtable based on two specific columns
    }

    static Hashtable AnotherWay() => 
        Library
            .RandomDataTable()
            .ToHashtable(0,1); // build a hash table based on the first and second column
}
```

What you would need to do on your end is proper null checks, as I have omitted them here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having, might be the structure of the table, such as column names or datatype,
check if the column names you are using in the code match the column names in the table you are querying.

Check if this helps:
To convert **DataTable to HashTable**

```
public static Hashtable ConvertDataTableToHashTable(DataTable dt)
{
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ht.Add(dr[0], dr[1]); // Assuming the first column contains keys and the second column contains values
    }
    return ht;
}
```

To convert **SQLDataReader to HashTable**

```
 public static Hashtable ConvertDataReaderToHashTable(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            // Assuming the first column contains keys and the second column contains values
            ht.Add(dr[0], dr[1]); 
        }
        return ht;
    }
```

you can use JavaScriptSerializer to serialize it into JSON format that can be parsed by JavaScript.

```
Hashtable ht = ConvertDataTableToHashTable(dt); // Assuming dt is your DataTable object
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(ht);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq there is usually a way without writing a foreach loop.

```
// Just for testing
var test = new DataTable();
test.Columns.Add("orderNumber");
test.Columns.Add("customerName");
test.Rows.Add(155, "Customer 1");

// Creating the Hashtable
Hashtable test2 = new Hashtable(
   test.Select()
       .Select(_ => new Tuple<string, string>(_.ItemArray[0].ToString(), _.ItemArray[1].ToString()))
       .ToDictionary(_=>_.Item1));
```

First you should validate if your Datatable has the two columns needed, otherwise this wont work.
The first .Select() just returns all your data rows as collection.
The second .Select() is from Linq, it basically converts each DataRow into the specified format. In this case a simple Tuple.
Using this Collection of Tuples you can now create a Dictionary, wich is used when creating a new Hashtable.

But if you are not used to Linq, you shold be careful and read about its methods before using them.

Also watch out when loading the whole datatable without using enumerators, thats heavy on the ressources.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a column into MD5 hash

Comment: and then you can compare two columns

Comment: Would you be able to provide short example code and include your comment as part of your answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static Hashtable Fn_ConvertDataTableToHashTable(DataTable dtTable, int iRow)
{
        Hashtable hshTable = new Hashtable();

        if (CommonUtil.Fn_CheckDatatableHasValue(dtTable))
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dtTable.Columns)
            {

                hshTable.Add(column.ColumnName, dtTable.Rows[iRow][column.ColumnName].ToString());
            }
        }

        return hshTable;
}
```